# I have a problem when i try to use chr python 3

Tags: python-3.x, chr

I'm using vs code, and when i try to run this:
`print(str(chr(257)))`
I get this error:`ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

Comment: Are you sure it's python3 and not python2 ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using a Python 2 interpreter to run Python 3 code. As noted in the [docs for that function in Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#chr):

> The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive; ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range

Switch the interpreter you're using in VS Code to a Python 3 interpreter.